# "Kernel Panic" on booting from live usb

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb, error-handling

I am trying to install Lubuntu on [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&product=375243) old laptop. I first tried Ubuntu but when running live from usb, it gave me an error:
[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkown-block(2,8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sfn2.jpg)
I checked, the checksum is ok, noting with the graphics and tried to create the usb with Universal USB Installer and Unetbuntin. What is there to do?

**EDIT:** Also, GParted gave me a similar error. Up to date, the only OS that worked is DamnSmallLinux.

**EDIT:** The USB boot successfully and I am get to a menu where I can choose options, like memory testing, installing Lubuntu or booting without installing. After choosing an option(except memory testing, that one is fine), it pause for about 5 minutes then bring this error message.

Comment: What file system is on usb ?

Comment: Looks like the disk is not being set up correctly: it is trying to boot directly from a floppy disk rather than loading the initramfs and booting from the usb.  Try burning the image to a dvd instead.

Comment: It is using fat32. I will retry to boot from a CD, last time the laptop would get stuck for about a minute, sounded like he was trying to spin the CD and was failing, and after booted Windows from the hard drive. The weird thing, Windows could read the CD.

Comment: Live DVD not working. It boot, I chose an option, example install lubuntu, then pause for an eternity and does noting. You can hear the dvd reader spining, doing a little click and doing the same thing, spining, click... Begining to think it is an hardware problem. Also a little note, I am using a DVD-RW.

Comment: Spoke to fast, live USB with alternate lubuntu seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working. I installed [alternate Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) on a USB with Unetbuntin, booted the computer and worked! Hope this will help other persons with a similar problem.